# Puppeteer cannot find Xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath, puppeteer

I am trying to get into web scraping and I got my hands on a website that looked quite easy to **scrape**. However, this website has many elements with the same ID, which makes it difficult to use selectors.

I am thus trying to get an element using its full XPath. The problem is that when I open the Chrome console on the website and type :

`$x("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")`

It sometimes work, and sometimes does not. I noticed that it works especially after inspecting the element. I found on other threads that it may be related to the iframe, but the chrome console's iframe selection doesn't seem to change when it works or doesn't work.

Using Puppeteer, this expression ALWAYS returns an empty element. Here is an extract of my code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const URL = "https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england_2019&pmtype=bygameweek";
let browser = await puppeteer.launch(properties);

let page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(URL, {timeout: 60000, waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}).then(() => {
    console.log('success')
});

let match_xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]";
await page.waitForXPath(match_xpath);
let match = (await page.$x(match_xpath))[0];
let info = await page.evaluate((el) => {
                    return el.innerHTML
           }, match);
console.log(info) //This always returns 'undefined'
```

Why is it behaving this way ? How can I get the actual content of the element ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I want to get the content of the element linked by the XPath. In this case, it would be the name of the playing teams.

Comment: As an aside, why such a long xpath?  As soon as any element or variation is introduced in the web page, then it will break easily. Consider "//table[id='some_id_of_table']//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]", it is less fragile or something like that.

Comment: Would this also work if elements IDs are not unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code in your puppeteer script doesn't wait the element to be displayed in the browser (DOM).
So you can set `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` to wait the XHR (AJAX) request finished and displayed in the browser.

This code below to scrape the first table only

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const URL = 'https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england_2019&pmtype=bygameweek'

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : true,
        devtools : false
    })
    const [page] = await browser.pages()

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
    page.setRequestInterception(true)

    page.on('request', request => {
        if ( request.resourceType() === 'image' ) {
            request.abort()
        } else {
            request.continue()
        }
    })

    await page.goto(URL, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})

    const teams = await page.evaluate( () => {

        const teams = []
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabbertab:not(.tabbertabhide):not(.tabbertabdefault)  #btable > tbody > tr:not(.even) > td:not([align])').forEach(item => teams.push(item.innerText.trim()) )
        return teams

    })

    console.log (teams)

    await browser.close ()

})()
```

And if you want to get all of the teams inside of each `#btable`, you can use this code.

PS: I'm not using xPath because it's not easy to use it, and also it's prone to error.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const URL = 'https://www.soccerstats.com/results.asp?league=england_2019&pmtype=bygameweek'

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : true,
        devtools : false
    })
    const [page] = await browser.pages()

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
    page.setRequestInterception(true)

    page.on('request', request => {
        if ( request.resourceType() === 'image' ) {
            request.abort()
        } else {
            request.continue()
        }
    })

    await page.goto(URL, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})

    const allRoundTeams = await page.evaluate( () => {

        var allRoundTeams = []

        document.querySelectorAll('#btable').forEach(item => {
            if (item.querySelector('tbody > tr > td > b') !== null) {

                var title = item.querySelector('tbody > tr > td > b').innerText.trim().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

                var teams = []
                item.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr:not(.even) > td:not([align])').forEach(team => {
                    teams.push(team.innerText.trim())
                })
                allRoundTeams.push({
                    title : title,
                    teams : teams
                })
            }
        })

        return allRoundTeams

    })

    allRoundTeams.forEach(round => {
        console.log(round.title)
        console.log('========')
        round.teams.forEach(team => {
            console.log (team)
        })
        console.log('\n')
    })

    await browser.close ()

})()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) However, as I stated, some elements ID's are not unique through the page, and #btable is one of these ID's, which is why I use XPaths. I am able to retrieve the infos using the selector, but it works only for the first #btable... Does this code stand for retrieving the elements using the XPath ?

Comment: I've edited my code so you can retrieve all of the playing teams name in every rounds available. Please accept this as an answer if this worked perfectly.

PS: I'm not using xPath selector, because it's hard to debug and very prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath expression with your code; it should return the dates, team names and scores for Round 1, for example:

```
//div[2]//table[2]//td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]
```